# The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Object

Tags: node.js, base64, filereader, arraybuffer

I'm trying to send an image file (converted into Uint8Array) to the server using post request.

How do I read this image file on the server side and convert it into `'base64'` string at server side.

My code snippet is below

```
    let image = null
     document.getElementById('img').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
       const img = event.target.files[0]
      try {
        let file = new FileReader()
        file.readAsArrayBuffer(img)
        file.addEventListener("load", () => {       
          this.image = new Uint8Array(file.result)   
        })
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
      }
    })
    
    var data = {image: this.image}

    axios.post('http:localhost:8080/post/upload', data, {headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}})
    .then((response) => {
       if(response) {
         console.log(response.data)
       }
    }).catch((err) => {
         console.log(err)
    })
```

My backend code snippet is below:

```
    private_router.post('/post/upload', async(req: express.Request, res: 
    express.Response) => {
      let img = null
      fs.readFile(req.body.image, (err, data) => {
        if(err) console.log(err)
        else img = data
      })
      if(img != null) {
        console.log(img)
        return res.status(200).json({message: 'posted'})
      }
       res.status(200).json({message: 'posted'})

      })
```

When I make a post request using above code I get following error:

```
  (node:22468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: 
The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Object
```

I'm using Node.js as my backend.

Comment: You get this error on the nodejs-backend? Can you add the node.js code?

Comment: added backend code

Comment: try moving the post INTO the scope of the onLoad event , as you read the image file. The   post as it is now may be executing BEFORE the image file is even loaded.